# Connection Request dependency and order

Tags: codenameone

When my CN1 app starts I have to do 3 Connection Request.
If first one fails the app don't have to do last 2 request and so on for the second.

(3rd request is not necessary if second one fails)

How can I set the connection requests order?

Answer (score 1):

For standard `ConnectionRequest` calls you can use `addResponseListener()` and only add the next one in the response listener of the previous.

The `Rest` call has a completion callback in the fetch methods.

Alternatively you can use the synchronous versions of the methods e.g. `addToQueueAndWait()` for `ConnectionRequest` or `get*` in the `Rest` API.

Comment: ok thanks. How can I catch timeout exc on all connection request?
Something like:
`addNetworkErrorListener(err -> {
            // prevent the event from propagating
            err.consume();
            if(err == socket timeout exception) {
                // timeout
            }
        });`

Comment: There's no explicit catch for timeout. It's an error like other errors